# RichTextBox does not Update in real time even when using Invoke

Tags: .net, multithreading, user-interface, invoke

I'm using vb .NET in Visual Studio 2013. I have a RichTextBox which I'm using like a console. I want it to update automatically, but it only updates once the application is finished. So I tried using invoke, but it still doesn't update.

```
Private Sub AddTextToConsole(text As String)
    ConsoleText = text
    If rtbConsole.InvokeRequired = True Then
        rtbConsole.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf test))
    Else
        rtbConsole.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf test))
        'rtbConsole.AppendText(ConsoleText)
        'rtbConsole.SelectionStart = rtbConsole.Text.Length
        'rtbConsole.ScrollToCaret()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub test()
    '  MsgBox(ConsoleText)
    rtbConsole.AppendText(ConsoleText)
    rtbConsole.SelectionStart = rtbConsole.Text.Length
    rtbConsole.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that InvokeRequired always returns false. So I tried commenting out the else part and replaced it with another invoke. It goes into test() but still doesn't update until the app is finished. I tried using a msgbox in test() and then all text was updated in real time (as expected).

I've also tried some other examples from the internet like this one

```
Dim mi As MethodInvoker = AddressOf test
    Me.Invoke(mi)
End Sub
```

but to no avail. No matter what I do rtbConsole is never updated in real time.

Comment: Code works.  Obviously, you can just call `Test()` in your Else block.  The problem is somewhere else in your code that we can't see.  What is calling `AddTextToConsole` in your code?  You should be passing the text you want to update the control with as a parameter.  ConsoleText looks like a global variable, and that will cause you problems.

Comment: Yes, ConsoleText is a global variable. I used it because I didn't know how to pass arguments with MethodInvoker(AddressOf test). I was going to change that as soon as I got the basic concept working. I removed the global variable with a hard coded text and I still get the same results. So this can't really be the problem.

Comment: Yes, ConsoleText is a global variable. I used it as a preliminary solution because I didn't know how to pass arguments with MethodInvoker(AddressOf test). I removed the global variable with a hard coded text and I still get the same results. So this can't really be the problem.

I have a form with a few input fields and buttons. I have a button.Click handler and then I perform a few basic functions like checkinput() or SAPLogin(). AddTextToConsole is in the login function, before I remote call a SAP transaction and when I check error table. rtbConsole.InvokeRequired ALWAYS returns false.

Comment: I didn't say the ConsoleText was the issue at hand, I just suggested it would probably cause you problems (other problems).  Your issue is still what is calling AddTextToConsole.  You didn't document that, so no on can help you.

Comment: AddTextToConsole is called several times during the process as I have mentioned above. Here is an example:

EDIT: Stackoverflow is ignoring all my formating again

    Private Sub bnKalk2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)          Handles bnKalk2.Click
      Try
            Dim result As Boolean = False

            If checkinput() = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If login() = False Then Exit Sub

            AddTextToConsole(My.Resources.Resource.StartingTransaction & "CK11n (Kalkulationsvariante 2)" & n)

    result = CK11n(MATNR, KLVAR2)
...

Comment: Let's try again. I don't understand why Stackoverflow ignores any formatting that is not in the OP.

     Private Sub bnKalk2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnKalk2.Click 
    Try 
    Dim result As Boolean = False 
    If checkinput() = False Then Exit Sub 
     End If If login() = False Then Exit Sub     AddTextToConsole(My.Resources.Resource.StartingTransaction & "CK11n (Kalkulationsvariante 2)" & n) 
    result = CK11n(MATNR, KLVAR2)

Comment: Code is supposed to go in the body of the question.  That is what the edit link is for.  Four space indent.  Why do you even care about InvokeRequired if you are calling this method from a button click?  This is all happening on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: I just called InvokeRequired to be sure. I guess it really doesn't make sense. Anyway, the problem remains the same. The program goes through the entire button click even before it updates the RichTextBox and none of the invoke methods I have tried trigger a timely update